# Mouse buttons wrong way round

Tags: mouse

I have installed Ubuntu and it seems my left and right click are the wrong way round, i.e., my left click is the right click and right click is the left click. How do I swap them back?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to **System Settings --> Mouse & Touchpad** and You should see radio buttons to set your primary button

[image]